# How to get a specific piece of data clicked on and send it as part of AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, this

I have a sliding bar that has different values throughout it depending on which part of the sliding bar is clicked on. The ranges in my javascript represent the values. I am trying to pass the value selected to an ajax script, but cannot figure out how to do this.

I have tried doing this:

```
var range_selected      = $("#sliderInterval").this.ranges.val();
```

But I get this error for the line above ^^:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ranges' of undefined`

What can I do to capture the range the user clicks on and send it through with my AJAX data?

```
<div id="sliderBar">
  <div id="sliderInterval">
    <span id="sliderIntervalBudget">BUDGET</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

  var ranges = [{
    lower: 500,
    upper: 1000
  }, {
    lower: 1100,
    upper: 2000
  }, {
    lower: 2100,
    upper: 5000
  }, {
    lower: 5100,
    upper: 10000
  }, {
    lower: 11000,
    upper: 20000
  }, {
    lower: 21000,
    upper: 50000
  }, ];
  var wslider = $("#sliderBar").width() / (ranges.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var range = $('<div class="rangedot"><div class="intervalCircle"></div></div>');
    var left = (100 / (ranges.length) * i);
    rangeleft = "calc(" + left + "% - 2px)";
    range.css({
      left: rangeleft,
      width: wslider
    });
    range.on("click", function(idx) {
      return function() {
        var sliderleft = wslider * idx;
        $("#sliderInterval").animate({
          left: sliderleft
        });
        $("#budgetAmount").text("$" + ranges[idx].lower.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + " - " + "$" + ranges[idx].upper.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
      };
    }(i));
    $("#sliderBar").append(range);
    $("#sliderInterval").css("width", wslider + "px");
  }
  //$("#sliderInterval").show().text("BUDGET");
  $("#budgetAmount").show().text("$500 - $1,000");
});
```

Comment: Kindly can you tell me which slider plugin have you used ?

Comment: I am not using a slider plugin. What you see there is it minus the styling.

Comment: Please include your code here with output. I hope this link would be useful to you.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110154/318125